# If + past conditional clause

Tags: meaning

Here are the two examples. Could anyone tell me if they are both correct and have completely the same meaning?

1)If I'd been paying more attention I wouldn't have taken the wrong exit off the motorway.

2)If I was paying more attention I wouldn't have taken the wrong exit off the motorway.

Comment: 'If I was/were paying more attention I wouldn't just have taken the wrong exit off the motorway.' sounds quite idiomatic to me; version (1) is better to signal an event solidly in the past.

Answer (score -2):

I would go with option #1.
Although option #2 is not wrong ,it's just a very strange sounding sentence structure.

Comment: Why would you go with option 1? What makes option 2 sound strange?